# Sublime Text 2 / Terminal package / PS.bat not found

Tags: batch-file, powershell, terminal, sublimetext2

Whenever I try to open Terminal in ST2 I get the following error:

```
Terminal: The terminal C:\users\name\appdata\roaming\sublime text 2\packages\terminal\ps.bat was not found
```

But there is a PS.bat file in there and its contents are as follows:

```
start powershell -noexit -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "%APPDATA%\Sublime` Text` 2\Packages\Terminal\PS.ps1"
```

And when I double click it, it opens to the blue windows powershell terminal that used to open up in ST2.

Any idea what I can do to make it work again in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1):

Very stupid of me. It wasn't working because I was trying to open Terminal with no files open; when I opened up a .scss file from one of my projects and tried it, it worked.